# Android : How can i Auto Log out from my app when i change my status to false in Sql server?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have used Following things in my app :
1] MainActivity [Login Page]
2] Welcome [Home Page]

**I used .NET Web Service** and
Database : Table name **tblLogin**
Fields are:
          id , name , password , Status

**1] MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.yashdesai.myapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
    final String URL = "http://192.168.11.16/Lucky/WebService.asmx";

    EditText tv;
    EditText tv1;
    Button btn;
    TextView tv2;

    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
      //  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(session.isLoggedIn()==true){
            HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
            String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
            String password = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),welcome2.class);
            i.putExtra("name",name);
            startActivity(i);
        }
      //  session.checkLogin();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new MyTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }




    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String response = "";

        public void onPreExecute() {


                super.onPreExecute();

        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("name", tv.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("password", tv1.getText().toString());

            final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                response = result.toString();
                Log.d("REsponse rsult:       ", response.toString());



            } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
                soapFault.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                response = "1";

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                response = "2";
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String res) {

            if(!(res.equalsIgnoreCase("")))
            {
                tv2.setText(res);
                if(tv2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("not valid")){
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect username or password!", 9000).show();
                }
                else {

                        session.createLoginSession(tv.getText().toString(), tv1.getText().toString());

                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),welcome2.class);
                        i.putExtra("name",tv.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(i);
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

**2] Welcome2.java**

```
public class welcome2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t;
    String user_status="off";

    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome2);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wname);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        t.setText("Welcome: " + value);
    }

    public void logout(View view){

        session.logoutUser();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  timer = new CountDownTimer(1 *10 * 1000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //Some code
           // timer.start();
            t.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if(tv.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("not valid"))
                if(tv1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("not valid"))

                session.logoutUser();

            else{}
        }

    }.start();}
```

Hope it works for you.!

Answer (score 0):

```
  private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            Toast.makeText(welcome2.this,"in runnable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // Toast.makeText(welcome2.this,"in runnable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //session.logoutUser();

            //welcome2.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 5000);
        }

    };
```